# Azure Container Instance Pricing

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-container-instances, azure-webapps

I am trying to deploy a ASP net core web application in Azure Container Instance. Since it is having a microservice pattern I had to create 3 container groups for 2 API's and 1 for the web application. Each container group is having one application container and an nginx side cart to act as a reverse proxy. But I have getting around 120$ bill for these container instances alone. Each container is allocated 0.2GB Ram and 0.2GB CPU.

I am pretty new to Container instances and I am not sure if my approach is correct? Can any one suggest is it the right approach for hosting the application and also am I missing or misconfiguring some configurations while creating the container instances?

Comment: It depends on lot of configuration details, what is the OS, there is no ACI with 0.2gb and 0.2gb cpu as far as i know. you can use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

Comment: I am using Linux boxes for hosting. Also the 0.2gb 0.2cpu configurations I just tried and configured them in the yaml file.

Comment: check the price calculator